# No alive nodes found in your cluster in Laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I try to implement Elastic Search in my Laravel v5.8 Project, but i getting error "No alive nodes found in your cluster".

and i am use this Package for Elastic search
"elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master"

```
public function search()
{
    $movies = Movie::searchByQuery([
        'match' => [
            'title' => 'Vertigo'
        ]
    ]);
    return $movies;
}
```

i refer below link
https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/.

Comment: got any solution on this? @Mitesh